# Tikz inside gnuplottex

Tags: latex, gnuplot, tikz

Here is such a code.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[miktex]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{gnuplot}
        set terminal epslatex color
        set xrange [-4:4]
        set yrange [0:16]
        set xlabel '$x$'
        set ylabel '$y$'
        plot x**2 title '$y=x^2$'
    \end{gnuplot}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to draw primitives using tikz in a coordinate system created by gnuplot, similar to pgfplots? For example, `\draw (axis cs:0 , 0) -- (axis cs:1 , 1)`;

Comment: Your code is not compilable for me, but I don't have miktex. Is it working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably many ways of doing so, here is a solution using the tikzlibrary `tikzmark`, which puts a custom mark called "a" in the ylabel string (but which could also be placed by an arbitrary `set label` command).
Your code was not compilable for me; one of the reasons is that the `set terminal` command has to be provided as an option to `\begin{gnuplot}` instead of inside the gnuplot code. Since you want to use tikz I would recommend to use the tikz terminal anyway.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{gnuplot-lua-tikz}
\usepackage{gnuplottex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
 \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=tikz]
  set xrange [-4:4]
  set yrange [0:16]
  set xlabel '$x$'
  set ylabel '$\tikzmark{a}y$'
  plot x**2 title '$y=x^2$'
 \end{gnuplot}
    
An arrow going from the $y$ label to exactly here.\tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw[<-, bend angle = 10, bend right] (0,0) to (pic cs:a);

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please tell me where to get this package "gnuplot-lua-tikz"?

Comment: @Дмитрий It comes as a part of a gnuplot installation, so it depends on your OS and how you installed gnuplot. As for me (Opensuse Tumbleweed), I compiled gnuplot from source and set the `--with-texdir` flag accordingly, but for you a different approach might be needed.

Comment: How does miktex understand that this package is installed?

Comment: @Дмитрий I am not entirely sure, but I think at some point during the installation `texhash` is called. Anyway, this in unrelated to your original question; if you need assistance with the installation of gnuplot you should ask a separate question.